# Savings account app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, math, pow

Hi I'm trying to make a app where it takes your capital * the rent raised to the amount of years. So it calculates how much it has grown.

But i have encountered a problem whit the pow i want it to pow the rent to the amount of years but i only get it to 1 unless i use a higher value. I have tried using float and double whit no luck. I´m really grateful for any help received enter.

```
func dismissKeyboard() {

    responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)


    let myInt: Int? = Int(kapital.text!)    
    let myInt1: Int? = Int(år.text!)
    let myInt2: Int? = Int(ränta.text!)

    let ab = 100.00000
    let a = 1.00000
    let faktor = Double(myInt2!) / Double(ab)
    let faktor1 = Double(faktor) + Double(a)

    let fx: Int = Int(pow(Double(faktor1),Double(myInt1!)))

    let result =  Double(fx) * Double(myInt!)
    duhar.text = "\(result)"


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the result of pow to an Int, here:

`let fx: Int = Int(pow(Double(faktor1),Double(myInt1!)))`

Doing that will drop any decimal and round down to the nearest integer, try this instead:

`let fx = pow(faktor1, Double(myInt1!))`